# Assign a method from one class to an instance of another

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

As the title suggests, I would like to assign all the instance methods defined on one class to another. I know at I can get a list of the methods that I want to copy from `ClassA` to `ClassB` like this:

```
ClassA.instance_methods(false)
```

And I think I can define them on `ClassB` like this:

```
ClassA.instance_methods(false).each do |method_name|
  ClassB.method_define(method_name, [body here??])
end
```

Is there a way to get the corresponding method body, and if so, will this method work? If not, is there even a way to do this?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  Any reason you can't use mix-ins /modules to accomplish this?

Comment: @John: I don't think that the OP is a noob who doesn't understand the concept of subclassing. Why don't you take his question literally?

Comment: Your code contradicts your title. You want ClassA and ClassB (not a single instance of it) share the same methods. John Naegle's answer is the right one : move all instance methods of ClassA to a module, then include this module into both classes.

Answer (score 10):

Others already told you to subclass. But to answer your literal question, we would be getting involved with `UnboundMethod` objects:

```
class Object
  def kokot; 'kokot' end
end

o = Object.new
o.kokot
#=> kokot

3.kokot
#=> kokot
```

So far so good. Now let's redefine `kokot` method on `Numeric`:

```
class Numeric
  def kokot; 'pica' end
end

o.kokot
#=> kokot
3.kokot
#=> pica
```

But what if we decide, that new `kokot` method is great for numerics, but just complex numbers should keep using the old `kokot` method. We can do it like this:

```
um = Object.instance_method :kokot
#=> #<UnboundMethod: Object#kokot>
Complex( 2, 3 ).kokot # gives the redefined kokot method
#=> pica
Complex.module_exec { define_method :kokot, um }
# Now we've just bound the old kokot to Complex
Complex( 2, 3 ).kokot
#=> kokot
```

In short, there is a way to "copy and paste" methods among related classes. **It is required that the target be a subclass of the unbound method source.** Method `#source_location` shows the file and the line where `#kokot` has been defined:

```
um.source_location
#=> ["(irb)", 2]
```

For built-in methods, `#source_location` returns `nil`. In Ruby 2.0, `RubyVM` class has method `#disassemble`:

```
RubyVM::InstructionSequence.disassemble( um )
#=> ( program listing goes here )
```

In any case, Ruby bytecode is not that beautiful to look at. Going back to your original needs, not even `#define_method` or `UnboundMethod#bind` can bind methods to incompatible objects. This cannot be cheated by tricks like redefining `#kind_of?`, one would have to cheat CLASS_OF() function in the native code...

From the available gems, [Sourcify](https://github.com/ngty/sourcify), [RubyParser](https://github.com/seattlerb/ruby_parser) and [Sorcerer](https://github.com/jimweirich/sorcerer) are of interest. (Thanks, @Casper.) Using these, one could theoretically transplant code between incompatible objects via `#eval`-ling extracted method source. Long way as it goes, this technique would still fall short of realiable method transfer, as it fails whenever the source is not available at runtime (eg. self-modifying source).

Comment: I do not use Ruby but dobrá odpoveď! :D

Answer (score 3):

It seems like what you might want is mix-ins:

Taken from http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/tut_modules.html

```
module Debug
  def whoAmI?
    "#{self.type.name} (\##{self.id}): #{self.to_s}"
  end
end
class Phonograph
  include Debug
  # ...
end
class EightTrack
  include Debug
  # ...
end
ph = Phonograph.new("West End Blues")
et = EightTrack.new("Surrealistic Pillow")
ph.whoAmI?  »   "Phonograph (#537766170): West End Blues"
et.whoAmI?  »   "EightTrack (#537765860): Surrealistic Pillow"
```

Comment: Seems to me the appropriate answer :)

Answer (score 1):

In ruby 2.0 you can use modules. Matz explicitly [forbade this behavior from classes](http://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/4254).

But you can use instance_methods from modules.

```
ModuleA.instance_methods(false).each do |name|
  meth = ModuleA.instance_method(name)
  ClassB.send(:define_method, name, meth)
end
```

`define_method` is a private method, so that's why you use `send` here.

But why do this? Just include the module.

If you want to just apply behavior to an object you can unbind a method from any module and bind it to any object.

```
ModuleA.instance_method(:something).bind(some_object).call(args)
```

If this is what you want, take a look at `casting`, a [gem that adds a convenience to doing delegation](https://github.com/saturnflyer/casting) like this as well as adding methods to an object only for the life of a block.

Answer (score 0):

In that case, `classB` should inherit `classA`.